# How to unblock washer jets?

Tags: opel, windshield-washer, agila

My washer jets are blocked up on the driver's side. I cannot get any water on this side to wash the windscreen.

Is there anything I can use to unblock them?

EDIT: It seems the blockage is in the squirter itself, as it only happens on the driver's side. The passenger's works fine.

If it was in the tubes, would I have to take the entire bonnett apart?

Comment: Where is the blockage, at the squirter itself? Have you checked to ensure it's coming from the tube, that it isn't blocked before the squirter? Just a thought. This is a question which I've wondered before as well. I'm thinking there isn't an easy fix, but you could try pulling the tube from the squirter and then squirting WD-40 *back* through the nozzle (from the side the water comes out of). This may force whatever is blocking it back down the hole if the problem is at the squirter in the first place.

Comment: After update: If you cannot get to the tubing from underneath, then, yes you'd need to take whatever part of the bonnet apart to get at where the tubing attaches to the squirter.

Comment: I'm going to replace the jets, and see what that does. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried unblocking them with pins, but they turned out to be really blocked.

In the end, I simply bought some new mist washer jets on eBay. It was like £5, and I was going to upgrade anyway.

I simply fitted them myself by hacking them slightly, by **trimming** down the plastic stumps. Do NOT cut off too much, or you will need to buy some more as they won't stay in!

Then getting two small screwdrivers, opening the bonnet, and sticking the screwdrivers in the holes in order to unclip the old ones. Then I twisted the pipes off. Make sure you hold the pipe at the end, or otherwise you will tear the pipe, like I did!

Then push the new ones in, and make sure they work before clicking them back in.

Answer (score 4):

I've personally had success clearing these nozzles using a sewing pin; the type that a seamstress may use to pin a garment together just before it is sewn.

You can not only use the pin to clear the nozzle but you can also use it to adjust the area of the screen that it's point at once it's been cleared.

Answer (score 3):

The Nozzle is the bottle neck, therefore that is the most likely place for a clog.  Pull the hose from the back of the nozzle and use a needle to clear the blockage and reattach the hose, making sure that no debris are remaining in the hose/nozzle.

Answer (score 2):

Some owner's manuals will recommend using a needle or small pin to dislodge debris that causes clogging or misdirection of flow.

It is normal for the spray nozzles to get clogged in dusty environments; you shouldn't have to replace them.